# Factorial Caps Out

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that calculates factorials from zero to fifty and then outputs it to the user. However I could only set my integer 'n' to a maximum of forty-six, otherwise the output isn't correct and only calculates factorials from four to fifty.

```
   for (int n = 0; n <= 50; n++)
    {
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1");
        int x;

        for (x = 1; x <= n; x++)
        {
            result = result.multiply(new BigInteger("" + x));
        }

        System.out.println (n + ": " + result);
    }
```

Comment: How are you seeing that? Are you sure it's not just a matter of the output scrolling off the screen or something similar? Additionally, is there any reason you're not using the result of the previous factorial? You're doing the same computations multiple times for no reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with BlueJ, the IDE I was using. BlueJ automatically ends at a  certain number of outputs, so I had to enable Unlimited Buffering.